# Mmap a block device on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, memory, posix, mmap

I want to access an encrypted core storage volume in my program. 
My plan is to mmap the decrypting block device to be able to jump around in the file system structures with ease and without having to deal with the crypto myself.

While mapping a big file works like a charm, I am getting an EINVAL error on the mmap syscall in the following code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd = open("/dev/disk2", O_RDONLY); // this works fine
  if (fd < 0)
  {
    perror("Could not open file"); return(-1);
  }

  int pagesize = getpagesize(); // page size is 4096 on my system
  void* address = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FILE, fd, 0); // try to map first page
  if (address == MAP_FAILED)
  {
    perror("Could not mmap"); // Error complaining about an invalid argument
  }
}
```

The device has a size of 112 GB and I am compiling with `clang mmap.c -O0 -o mmap` on Mavericks 10.9.3 for x86_64. My system has 4 GB of RAM and > 10 GB of free hard disk space.

The man-Page mmap(2) only lists the following explanations for an EINVAL error, but these do not seem to apply:

> - MAP_FIXED was specified and the **addr** argument was not page aligned, or part of the desired address space resides out of the valid address space for a user process.
> - **flags** does not include either MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED.
> - The **len** argument was negative.
> - The **offset** argument was not page-aligned based on the page size as returned by *getpagesize(3*).
>
> [...]
>
> - The **flags** parameter must specify either MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED.
> - The **size** parameter must not be 0.
> - The **off** parameter must be a multiple of pagesize, as returned by **sysconf**().

While I have not figured out all the nitty gritty details of the implementation, the comments on this XNU kernel source file explicitly mention being able to map a block device (as long as it's shared): https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/bsd/kern/kern_mman.c

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check in the manual how errors are communicated?

Comment: Yes, in case of an error the return value is `MAP_FAILED` and `errno` is set to the appropriate error constant. So checking for either should be fine. In this case I am always getting `EINVAL` (= Invalid argument).

Comment: No, "checking either" is not fine at all. **If** `MAP_FAILED` is returned, **then** `errno` contains information about the error. Typically `errno` is not touched if there is no error.

Comment: Well yes, I stand corrected, you are right. The proper way is to check for the sentinel. Unfortunately that doesn't change anything as I was getting `MAP_FAILED` as return value all along. I updated source code to reflect that. Sorry about the omission.

Comment: Did you check the value of `pagesize`?

Comment: `getpagesize()` returns 4096 on my system.

Comment: I think you're falling foul of the check: `vp->v_type != VREG && vp->v_type != VCHR` i.e. the type is neither aregular file nor is it a character device

Comment: Well, the problem is: I can't mmap a character device either.
I am getting `ENODEV` (Operation not supported by device) supposedly because of this check a couple of lines further down `vp->v_type == VCHR || vp->v_type == VSTR`.

Again, am I missing something?
The method comment clearly states I should be able to map devices.
Is the implementation really broken?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: This won't make a difference, but .. the second argument `len` is not the page size but the length of the data you want to `mmap()`. You will need to do some DiskArbitration Framework magic to obtain the partition or disk size.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be using MAP_FILE since this indicates a regular file rather than a block device.

If that doesn't work, trying calling fstat() after you open the file and check the file's length.  When I use stat -x to get the information about the block devices on my system, the file sizes are reported as zero (ls -l reported the sizes as "1,").  A zero-length file might also prevent you from being able to create a mapping.